# React change custom drag image on the fly

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

Is there any chance to change custom drag image which has been set in `onDragStart` event
with `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(image, 0, 0)` on the fly during DnD process? For example, in the `onDragEnter` ?

Specification says, that dataTransfer has write access only for dragStart event, but may be somebody know another way to change it or set custom drag image without dataTransfer interface?
DnD logic is required because drag process supports cross-tab   + onDrop event has a lot complex logic, so I can not simply add listener for `mousemove` event and attach image to current mouse position.

The problem is to change drag image which  has been ALREADY set in dragStart event  to another image on  dragEnter event. I pretty sure that it is impossible by DnD API, but may be somebody had the same issue and resolved it by another way.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

I googled it and found [this article](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html).
Here is the snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    console.log('dragstart');
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://kryogenix.org/images/hackergotchi-simpler.png";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("drag", function(e) {
    console.log('drag')
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = null;
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

```css
.dragdemo {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-with-image" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>
```

It has a lot of helpful examples!

EDIT 1:
The `dragenter` event is fired on the drop target element when the draggable element is on top of it, not on the draggable element itself. What is called after `dragstart` is `drag` as you can see in your console when running the updated snippet above.
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragenter.asp) you can see that `dragstart`, `drag`, `dragend` are fired on the draggable element.
To be honest I don't know why `dragstart` or `drag` don't work for you! A more detailed code snippet would help

Comment: Thanks, but there is no problem set drag image on "dragStart", there is a problem change it with "dragEnter"

Comment: `dragenter` is used when you are inside the dropzone, is this where you want to change the image?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Unfortunately, I know everything you wrote. The problem is to change drag image which has been ALREADY set in dragStart event to another image on dragEnter event. I pretty sure that it is impossible by DnD API, but may be somebody had the same issue and resolved it by another way. I updated the topic to be sure that issue is described correctly

Comment: Yeap, gotcha, I'm pretty sure its not feasible with DnD :/